# Проверить имя пользователя при авторизации и вывести нужный контент

Tags: php, mysql

Есть главная страница, на которой проверяется авторизован пользователь или нет и для авторизованного выводится определенный контент.
Как сделать что бы проводилась еще проверка имени пользователя и при выполнении условия выводился через require контент для конкретного пользователя.
Вывести контент при выполнении условия могу, не знаю как проверить имя пользователя(еще мало знаю PHP)
Представляю примерно так как в JS: если имя пользователя = 123, тогда выводится код.

Comment: Ну вообще-то надо по имени (или чего там у пользователя) запрашивать из БД только предназначенные к показу ему данные. А показывать - всё полученное, ибо там уже ничего лишнего нет.

Comment: Я хотел сделать проще, сравнить данные имя пользователя, даже которое отображается в виде приветствия на странице с тем которое мне надо и при совпадении просто вывести  информацию.

Comment: Какое же это проще - притащить ВСЁ на клиента (трафик, память, никакой безопасности), а потом ещё и разгребать, надо или не  надо показывать...